# VB.NET Undo/Redo only the text in RichTextBox

Tags: vb.net

I just want to know how to make the undo/redo system in VB.NET's RichTextBox perform only undo/redo operations only on text.. which means it will not include the text formatting.

I am making a code editor and i change the fonts based on the keywords given by the user. When I press undo, instead of undoing the text, it changed the font first, which is not what i want.

I tried using custom undo/redo system using stacks, but it has many bugs.

Comment: theres a lot of example [here](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&espv=210&es_sm=93&q=richtextbox+undo+redo+c%23&oq=richtextbox+undo+redo+c%23&gs_l=serp.3..0i30.5672.6688.0.6828.5.5.0.0.0.0.157.641.1j4.5.0....0...1c.1.32.serp..1.4.485.t0jH3TVtpy4)

Comment: i searched for examples there but they only give the RichTextBox1.Undo() method..

by the way.. i don't have any background in c# so i cannot undestand most of the logic in their codes.

Comment: just try to change the word `C#` to `vb` then :)

Comment: i tried it first before searching for c#, but they are almost same.

Comment: Got any code you could post. And what are you trying to undo? The text entered?

Answer (score 0):

See this [Example](http://pradeep1210.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/undoredo-capable-textbox-winforms/) It's create Undo And Redo Function For **TextBox** But it's easy To Change To  **RichTextBox**

Tell Me If it's fit for you.

Comment: The link is didatically good but the op states he has tried using custom undo/redo system using stacks and that's exactly what this example does, the author also states there are unhandled use cases on that code (copy/paste) suggesting using his code may run into the same types of problems the op currently has. So it sounds like it's not a good solution unless it's found to be the only one